# Avoid that scaletikz scales text for subplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale

Say I have the following `tikzfigure`, which contains 3 subplots (created using `matlab2tikz`) which is severely to large to fit on a page.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.878in,
height=4.754in,
at={(2.966in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=7,
xlabel={xlabel},
ymin=-30,
ymax=-12,
ylabel={ylabel},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]

\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -12.8649565461571\\
2   -13.7476049223822\\
3   -14.6302532986073\\
4   -15.5129016748325\\ 
5   -16.3955500510576\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.878in,
height=4.754in,
at={(8.563in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=7,
xlabel={xlabel},
ymin=-16,
ymax=-8,
ylabel={ylabel},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]

\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   -8.77653300904041\\
2   -10.3274635147801\\
3   -11.8783940205199\\
4   -13.4293245262596\\
5   -14.9802550319994\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
width=3.878in,
height=4.754in,
at={(14.159in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
axis equal,
xlabel={xlabel},
ylabel={ylabel},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,mark=asterisk,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
-9.96578428466209   -3.29101293572018\\
-10.9657842846621   -3.52562937598178\\
-12.2877123795494   -3.92228491362964\\
-13.2877123795494   -3.58191482601903\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To scale it down I have tried to use `scaletikz`, as:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Which according to its [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale?lang=en) should respect the textsize, but if we compare with the unscaled version

```
\input{test.tikz}
```

It is clear that the labels have been scaled. How can I avoid this? I am aware of the `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]` solution, however, due to the large number of files, I would rather want an automated solution I can apply from document side (where I already apply `\includegrapics`), also using `scale` would make it very hard to fit exactly the pagewidth.

Comment: I have now updated it to a compilable example. I do not understand, what you mean with: "it does not contain any subfigures". There are 3 plots, which are placed next to each other, is this not subfigures?

Comment: Google "subfigure latex" and you will see what is meant.

Comment: Ohh, I had convinced myself that "subplots" and "subfigures" was the same. I have updated the question to reflect that I was talking about subplots. My apologies.

Comment: Are you sure it is related to subplots? You don't get the same effect otherwise? Because I get just the same effect with a single plot. I think the problem is that you are ignoring `tikzscale`'s guidelines for including `pgfplots`. Basically, you're scaling them with `pgfplots` independently. You need both a width and a height or to use, say, `axisratio` or whatever (unless you want the default, I guess) ***rather than*** using e.g. `scale only axis` etc.

Comment: The best approach is probably the include the plots individually, so that you can set scaling for each with `tikzscale`.